# Fragment не обновляется

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

У меня 2 `Activity` на одном `RecyclerView`, на другом `Fragment`. В `Activity` в котором `RecyclerView` все хорошо работает, он заполняется. 
В `Activity` с `Fragment`, он пустой.

Цель: Вывод динамичного  `RecyclerView` в `Activity` с использованием `Fragment`

Как решить данную проблему?

```
public class fragmentbilet  extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bilet_view,
            container, false);
    return myFragmentView;



}
```

Comment: Очевидно что надо заполнить `myFragmentView` данными, а не просто вернуть её после создания.

Comment: @temq как это сделать ? я заполняю данными 'Activity'

Comment: @VTeme, если вы заполняете данными активити, то данные нужно передать во фрагмент. По данному коду у вас пустой фрагмент получается. Попробуйте заполнять данными RecycleView во фрагменте.

Comment: @IvanVovk То есть мне нужно создать еще 1 Адаптер, и провести те же манипуляции, что и с активити ? или можно сделать это иначе ?

Comment: @VTeme, вынесите реализацию наполнения RecycleView во фрагмент. Мне кажется, что у вас совсем другая проблема. Что вы в итоге хотите получить, напишите в вопросе.

Comment: @IvanVovk Обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему отказавшись от использования Fragment

Answer (score 1):

В вашем фрагменте fragmentbilet не определен RecyclerView. Для того, что у вас заработал данный функционал нужно:

1. В разметке определить RecyclerView.
2. В реализации (читай коде) фрагмента найти его и заполнить данными.